# SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 65536. SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I want to ask something what error is this. I want to display report book to PHP but the result showing like in picture

[image: Error]

Here is my report book:

```
public function GetReportBook($id_book, $TanggalStart, $TanggalEnd)
    {
        // select all query
        try {
            require_once 'Database.php';
            $sqlsrvquery = (" EXEC [dbo].[GetReportBook] @id_book=id_book, @TanggalStart=TanggalStart, @TanggalEnd=TanggalEnd");
            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlsrvquery);
            $stmt->bindParam('id_book', $id_book, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('TanggalStart', $TanggalStart, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('TanggalEnd', $TanggalEnd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                print_r($r);
            }


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the result showing in ASP.NET:

[image: ASP.NET]

Comment: Use `:id_book` not `id_book` for the parameter name in `$this->conn->prepare` and `$stmt->bindParam`. You need to use named (:name) or question mark (?) parameter markers in the [prepared](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) statement.

Comment: Thanks. But here is the result SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Use an unabiguous datetime format (`yyyymmdd` or `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`) for the value of `$TanggalStart` and `$TanggalEnd` variables. BTW, what are the actual values of these variables (what does `var_dump($TanggalEnd)` return)?

Comment: actually the values for checking report base on Input TanggalStart and TanggalEnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the following:

- You need to use named (`:name`) or question mark (`?`) parameter markers in the [prepared](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) statement.
- You need to use an unambiguous datetime format (`yyyymmdd` in your case) for the value of `:TanggalStart` and `:TanggalEnd` parameters.

An example, based on your code:

```
public function GetReportBook($id_book, $TanggalStart, $TanggalEnd)
    {
        // select all query
        try {
            require_once 'Database.php';
            $sqlsrvquery = ("
               EXEC [dbo].[GetReportBook] 
                   @id_book = :id_book, 
                   @TanggalStart = :TanggalStart, 
                   @TanggalEnd = :TanggalEnd
            ");
            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sqlsrvquery);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id_book', $id_book, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':TanggalStart', date('Ymd', strtotime($TanggalStart)), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':TanggalEnd', date('Ymd', strtotime($TanggalEnd)), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                print_r($r);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```